# How to do applyFormat within a Gutenberg Block from an external call?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, wordpress-gutenberg, richtext

I am trying to apply a Richtext Format from an outside call. The only thing currently failing is the applyFormat. I am not getting any errors, but the format is not being applied either. The value passed to the dispatcher holds the new activeFormat, but it never gets applied. Any workaround ?

```
   var html = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectedBlock().attributes.content;
   var blockUid = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectedBlock().clientId;
   var value = wp.richText.create({
                  html 
                });
   value = wp.richText.applyFormat(value, { type: 'core/bold' }, 
           wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectionStart(), 
           wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectionEnd()
           );

    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).updateBlock( blockUid, {
           attributes: {
              content: wp.richText.toHTMLString(
                       {value } 
                        )
           }
    } );
```

Comment: Solved it. The start and end selection are actually objects :)  Using offset does the trick! 
I updated the example above for anyone, looking for a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. The start and end selection are actually objects :) Using offset does the trick! Below the working solution.

```
   var html = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectedBlock().attributes.content;
   var blockUid = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectedBlock().clientId;
   var value = wp.richText.create({
                  html 
                });
   value = wp.richText.applyFormat(value, { type: 'core/bold' }, 
           wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectionStart().offset, 
           wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSelectionEnd().offset
           );

    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).updateBlock( blockUid, {
           attributes: {
              content: wp.richText.toHTMLString(
                       {value } 
                        )
           }
    } );
```